# To disable the addressbar and standardbuttons bar in IE when my application lanches?

Tags: asp.net

when my application launches in the IE from start page to main page i want to hide the addressbar and the standardbuttons bar of IE through the codebehind and here am using masterpage concept so i have to write the code in master only i think so....can anyone help for this

Comment: Just curious... Why you want to do it ?  I would not like an application which does this to me.  If you could share with us the reason, may be there could be a better alternate way.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot disable address bar and button in IE from when the application starts unless using some ActiveX, Flash, ... Only if your application opens [new window popups](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) you could hide them.

Comment: How about opening a new Popup and closing the main window.

Comment: You can only close windows that you've opened manually with window.open.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way... It works atleast in IE 7... Not sure about other browsers...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 if (window.name == 'default') {
            window.name = 'Hai';
            window.open('main.html', '_self');  // Current html file name
        }
 else if(window.name == '') {
            window.name = 'Hai';
            window.open('main.html', '_self');  // Current html file name
        }
 else if(window.name == 'Hai') {
              // Use your application startup page here along with the desired options
        window.open('newfile.aspx','NEWWINDOWNAME', 'Status=0, location=0');  
                window.close();
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    This window automatically closes itself
</body>
</html>
```

The complete list of options are available [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml).

Hope this helps.

**Explanation : (AFAIK)**  Generally when javascript uses window.close method to close the active window, IE will ask for a confirmation from the user.  Such confirmation will not be asked when the window is a popup window opened previously by a javascript along with a name.

The above just fakes the same, by opening the same file in the same window but this time with a name.  As a result when window.close is executed, IE recognises the current window as a window opened using Javascript and as it also has a name, it just closes the same without confirmation.

Of course, I get a general Javascript alert at the beginning of the load, but since (I presume) you will be using aspx or other types, this problem will not be there.